# Posting complex type via option/select element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can category model (example given below) be passed

```
public class Category { 
     public Guid Id { get; set; }; 
     public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

using a select/option?

```
<select id="categories" name="Category">
    <option value="Id">Text</option>
</select>
```

As far as I understand this will bind normally but excluding `Title` property?

**EDIT**

`Viewmodel`

```
public class EditProductModelView { 
    [Required] Category Category { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

`Controller`

```
public ActionResult Edit(EditProductViewModel model) {
    // controller logic
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is not possible with standard select. but you could achieve it with a litte script. would this be an option? do you support jquery on your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add a hidden input for the title value and fill it with options the data-title attribute value whenever the selection option changes

```
<input id="categoriesTitle" type="hidden" name="Category.Title" />
<select id="categories" name="Category.Id">
    <option value="foo" data-title="this is foo">foo</option>
    <option value="bar" data-title="I am bar">bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For that to bind, I believe you would have to name the select-element `Id`.

```
<select id="categories" name="Id">
    <option value="foo">Text</option>
    <option value="bar">Text</option>
</select>
```

If your action then looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(Category model) {
    var modelId = model.Id; // Will be set to the chosen value
    var title = model.Title; // Will be null
}
```

Comment: My action method accepts complex view model as its only parameter. Of course I can pass category id as an additional parameter but it seems no good regarding the fact I'm using Automapper.

Comment: @brick I might have misunderstood your question. So what you want to do is to pass both the value and the content of the option when posting the form?

Answer (score 1):

Your model needs a place to get the selected Id, which is where you put your Required attribute

```
public class EditProductModelView { 
      [Required]
     public Guid SelectedCategoryId {get;set;}
}
```

And then name must match the property name in view model:

```
<select id="categories" name="SelectedCategoryId">
    <option value="SomeGuidHere">Text</option>
</select>
```

This is just because of how browsers handle the post.  They do not post the Text node, only the selected value, which in your case is the Id.

Comment: Well I get it) But I was hoping text node could be posted too.

Comment: What is in your controller that you need the text node as well?  Might be able to offer a suggestion.